# MVC Parameterless

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need some help to resolve this problem: I'm still learning how to use MVC; I try to solve a problem wherein an error shows when there are no parameters ( but can not find why: I understand that no parameters are passed but cannot find the point of error; I have created a Data, eManager.Domain, interfaces, but not so as you can pass the parameter only as needed -- the error is:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Data library > DataDepartamentSource.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using eManager.Domain;

namespace Data
{
    public interface DataDepartamentSource
    {
        IQueryable<Employee> Employees { get; }

        IQueryable<Department> Departments { get; }
    }
}
```

eManager.Domain Library > Department.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace eManager.Domain
{
    public class Department
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int IdDep { get; set; }
        public virtual string NameDep { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

eManager.Domain Library > Employee.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace eManager.Domain
{
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

On the website Principal Web:

Infrastructure > DepartmentDataBase.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace eManager.Domain
{
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Migrations > Configuration.cs:

```
namespace PluralSight_MVC_Ejercicio.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<PluralSight_MVC_Ejercicio.Infrastructure.DepartmentDataBase>
    {

        //public DepartmentDB() : base("DefaultConnection")
        //{

        //}

        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(PluralSight_MVC_Ejercicio.Infrastructure.DepartmentDataBase context)
        {

            context.department.AddOrUpdate(m => m.NameDep,
                new eManager.Domain.Department() { NameDep = "Developer" },
                new eManager.Domain.Department() { NameDep = "Human Resource" },
                new eManager.Domain.Department() { NameDep = "Marketing" },
                new eManager.Domain.Department() { NameDep = "Sales" }

                );
        }
    }
}
```

In Controllers > HomeController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using eManager.Domain;
using Data;
using PluralSight_MVC_Ejercicio.Infrastructure;

namespace PluralSight_MVC_Ejercicio.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        //seleccionar el entityframework database = agregar como new en (interfaces) con el nombre del DB que se usara con las 2 
        //tablas de employee y deparment
        //private DataDepartamentSource data = new DepartmentDataBase();

        private Data.DataDepartamentSource db = new DepartmentDataBase();

        public HomeController(DepartmentDataBase data)
        {
            db = data;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var alldepartment = db.Departments;

            return View(alldepartment);
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

In Views > Home > Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<eManager.Domain.Department>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NameDep)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NameDep)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.IdDep }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.IdDep }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.IdDep })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Well, I used the package manager console to create the database and I enabled the migrations, but I still can't show the information in the view... so, can anybody help me?

Comment: I might be wrong but I think MVC expects your `Controller` to have a parameterless constructor, which it doesn't.

Comment: For some reason I think its your HomeController that needs a constructor without a parameter. If it is then you probably aren't using it yet.

Answer (score 2):

(As it was mentioned in the comments.) AFAIK, MVC creates the controller for you, so it needs a default constructor. Also, a default constructor is not automatically generated for you if you add a constructor of your own.

Here is an overview of the MVC 5 pipeleine (I assume that's the version you're using):
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application
(Try the PDF version if you can't make out the diagram.)

You can see it shows a controller factory creating the controller for you.

Anyway, I think if you just add a default constructor, it would solve that error.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your `HomeController` expects an argument of type `DepartmentDataBase` when it is constructed, but in this case, ASP.NET MVC does not know how to initialise the controller with that argument in the absence of a custom controller factory. So, ASP.NET uses the default controller factory which only builds controllers with default (or parameter-less) constructors, which you do not have in your code.

You are doing the right thing by trying to inject your dependency in the constructor; you just need to add a container that comes with a custom controller factory. Personally, I use Unity Container, but you have other choices like Autofac and Castle Windsor.